# Problems with matrix multiplication - some negative results

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, fibonacci

I try to find Fibonacci numbers by using matrix multiplication. But I have a problem with negative results.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 1],[1, 0]])
b = np.array([[1, 1],[1, 0]])
for i in range(100):
    if b[0][0] < 0:
        print(i)
    b = np.matmul(b, a)
#output: 91, 93, 94, 95, 97
```

Is my math too poor to understand the negative results or is there something I have to consider in python / numpy?

Comment: At first I was happy with the solution of @clarked, but then I decided to write my own matrix multiplication function. Because of the python integer type, I am not limited to values below 2 ** 64. If somebody wants to see my dirty code, just let me know, but I have warned you! I have no PhD in math, so I do not really understand how to optimize that code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your math is correct. You are running into limitations on the size of type `int64`. The largest that `int64` can be is `(2**63) - 1`. Your matrices are of type `int64` which you can check with `a.dtype`.

If you look at iteration `i=90` before your first negative, you get

```py
[[7540113804746346429, 4660046610375530309],
 [4660046610375530309, 2880067194370816120]]
```

But the next Fibonacci number after `7540113804746346429` is `12200160415121876738 = 7540113804746346429 + 4660046610375530309` which is larger than `2**63 - 1`. So it cannot be represented as an `int64` type. This causes an overflow which you can read more about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), but that's why you get a negative.

Floating point gives you a much larger range of numbers you can represent. If you use floats instead of ints, you will avoid negative numbers. There a number of ways to do this, but the easiest would be to modify your initial matrix definitions of `a` and `b` to include a decimal like so:

```py
a = np.array([[1., 1.],[1., 0.]])                              
b = np.array([[1., 1.],[1., 0.]])
```

Then you will notice that all of your iterations will have positive numbers. Floating point can have its own sources of error though because not every number can be represented exactly, so you will have to decide better what you want based on your situation.

---

Side Note: Instead of using a for loop to get the nth iteration (100 in your code), you can use `b @ np.linalg.matrix_power(a, n)` which is equivalent to multiplying `a` by itself `n` times and then multiplying with `b` or `B @ A^n`. NumPy optimizes it, so it's more efficient.

Comment: Thank you very much your suggestion about the optimization. The code is not yet optimized. I will do it like this [example for Swift](https://medium.com/swlh/fibonacci-swift-playground-f56d1ff3ea99)